# Numbers in a table with dcolumn in different font?

Tags: tables, fonts, dcolumn

I am using beamer and the dcolumn package and cannot get the numbers within a table to be in a different font. I also cannot use the siunitx package because I have numbers in brackets. Before defining my own columns the following worked to have all the contents in the table in a different font:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{12 month differences in the regional unemployment rates}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
{
\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
\begin{tabular}{ >{$}l<{$} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4} d{2.4}}
\hline\hline

        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(6)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(7)}\\
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{growth\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{hire\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{sep\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{hire\_e\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{hire\_n\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{sep\_e\_rate}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{sep\_n\_rate}\\
\hline
\beta_{1}&      0.0014         &     -0.0020         &     -0.0034^{\ast\ast} &     -0.0008^{\ast} &     -0.0012         &     -0.0021^{\ast\ast} &     -0.0012         \\
            &    (0.0021)         &    (0.0014)         &    (0.0010)         &    (0.0003)         &    (0.0014)         &    (0.0005)         &    (0.0008)         \\
[1em]
\beta_{2}&     -0.0004         &     -0.0023         &     -0.0019^{\ast}  &     -0.0008^{\ast} &     -0.0016         &     -0.0013^{\ast\ast} &     -0.0006         \\
        &    (0.0021)         &    (0.0016)         &    (0.0007)         &    (0.0002)         &    (0.0016)         &    (0.0003)         &    (0.0005)         \\
\midrule
R^{2}  &       0.067         &       0.289         &       0.352         &       0.195         &       0.283         &       0.332         &       0.325         \\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you very much for your suggestions.

Comment: the posted code makes `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.35 \end{frame}` (I edited to change `l` to `>{$}l<{$}`)

Answer (score 2):

You *can* use parentheses with `siunitx`, but you have to reserve places for them with `table-space-pre-text` and  `table-space-post-text`. Here is a code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}
\caption{12 month differences in the regional unemployment rates}
\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\makebox[0pt]{
\fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
\sisetup{table-format=1.4, table-space-text-pre=(, table-space-text-post=)}
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{$}l<{$}*{7}{S}@{}}
\toprule\midrule
 & {(1)} & {(2)}& {(3)}& {(4)}& {c}{(5)} & {(6)}& {(7)}\\
 & {growth\_rate}& {hire\_rate}& {sep\_rate} & {hire\_e\_rate}& { hire\_n\_rate} & {sep\_e\_rate} & {sep\_n\_rate} \\
\midrule
\beta_{1}& 0.0014 & -0.0020 & -0.0034\textsuperscript{**} & -0.0008\textsuperscript{*} & -0.0012 & -0.0021\textsuperscript{**} & -0.0012 \\
 & {(}0.0021{)} & {(}0.0014{)} & {(}0.0010{)} & {(}0.0003{)} & {(}0.0014{)} & {(}0.0005{)} & {(}0.0008{)} \\
[1em]
\beta_{2}& -0.0004 & -0.0023 & -0.0019\textsuperscript{*} & -0.0008\textsuperscript{*} & -0.0016 & -0.0013\textsuperscript{**} & -0.0006 \\
 & {(}0.0021{)} & {(}0.0016{)} & {(}0.0007{)} & {(}0.0002{)} & {(}0.0016{)} & {(}0.0003{)} & {(}0.0005{)} \\
\midrule
R^{2} & 0.067 & 0.289 & 0.352 & 0.195 & 0.283 & 0.332 & 0.325 \\
\midrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this cool hint. Still if I change
    \fontfamily{lmss}\selectfont
to
    \fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont
it does not change the font of the numerical characters only of the text, so you suggestion does not solve my problem.

Comment: Do you want to use a serif font for the whole document?

Comment: No I just want a serif font for the table, so for the text and the numbers within the table